# Find blank cells in entire table without specifying all column names in OR condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There are 190 columns in my table and I trying to list out empty or blank cells. Already i know to check this condition in `where` clause by using `OR`, but for no. of 190 columns it seems very long work....So I Tried following query in order to list out null values but when i alter the query according to my criteria by changing in the place of `'IS NULL'` as `''` to get empty cells it doesn't works

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255) = N'dbo.[Sales_Five_Years]';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tb
    + ' WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql += N' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Please guide me, Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL tables are *not* the same as a spreadsheet. If you keep acting as if they are, you'll end up having to write horrible code, as you'll end up with here. If data in two "cells" is meant to be comparable (such that you would compare the two values directly with each other, or want both to be treated the same in all/most queries), then both of those cells ought to be in separate rows in the *same* column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT @sql += N' OR convert(varchar(50),' + Quotename(name) + ')='''''
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  [object_id] = Object_id(@tb);
```

check this example 
i didn't get any error.

```
CREATE TABLE pr1
  (
     col  VARCHAR(50),
     col1 VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO pr1
SELECT '',NULL
UNION
SELECT NULL,'a'
UNION
SELECT 'b','a'


SELECT @sql += N' OR convert(varchar(50),' + Quotename(name) + ')='''''
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  [object_id] = Object_id(@tb);

PRINT @sql

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql;
```

Comment: I get following error - `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: @CIPHER In the above code there is no varchar to numeric conversion. paste the full code in the question which u ran

Comment: Above mentioned is full query which i used to get rows which has null value.....please check it again the whole code on your's sql table if it possible.........

Comment: DECLARE variable tb and sql as like the question with new table name 'pr1'

Comment: I worked on your example and i accept it working fine but when i change your table according  to my criteria such as i changed second column data type into decimal instead of varchar(Because i have major columns as decimal)  and i get the same eroor .....pls check it........